# Google drive automatically give access to a specific folder

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to implement automatically give access to a specific user in google drive if he meets some specific requirements which are management in google spreadsheet?

Example a have a list of student in a google spreadsheet and if he submit a specific homework I want to give him specific access in google drive automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to grant access via API using [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions). The only thing you need to control is how would you know that the user has submitted an specific homework.

If you keep track on a spreadsheet, for example. You can grant access within the spreadsheet using Apps Script and the class [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file).